# SQL query - make conditions conditional?

Tags: mysql, insert, insert-update

I have two tables (these are just the simplified versions):

```
`Locations`:
id  city  country  area
--  ----  -------  ----
71  C     X        E             
72  C     B        E             
73  C     F        G             
74  L     X        E
75  M     N        O
76  M     N        E          

`Findings`:
ID  city  country  area  resultVM
--  ----  -------  ----  --------
18                       empty
19  C                    lam  
20        X              lam8    
21                 E     pdg4
```

Now, I want to write an insert that fills up a third table, according to the data in these two. It should contain all the ids from the Location table once (Summed.locations_id is a ref to Locations.id obviously), and a matched resultVM from the Findings table. Result should be:

```
`Summed`:
locations_id   resultVM
------------   --------
71             lam        
72             lam        
73             lam        
74             lam8
75             empty
76             pdg4
```

The criteria are: first try matching the city to find a resultVM in the Findings table, if there is no result then match the country, then the area, and finally if there are no results at all then the empty line where no city/country/area is filled.

Currently I am doing this with 4 inserts/updates on duplicate keys, but since the tables are very large that takes a lot of time. Does anyone know if this can be done in a single update/insert/anything (in MySQL)?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do **left join.**

```
 INSERT INTO Summed (locations_id,resultVM)
    SELECT Locations.`id` AS locations_id,(CASE WHEN Findings_city.`city` IS NOT NULL THEN Findings_city.`resultVM`
                           WHEN Findings_country.`country` IS NOT NULL THEN Findings_country.`resultVM`
                           WHEN Findings_area.`area` IS NOT NULL THEN Findings_area.`resultVM`
                            ELSE 'empty'END) AS resultVM
    FROM
    Locations 
    LEFT JOIN Findings Findings_city ON Locations.`city` = Findings_city.`city`
    LEFT JOIN Findings Findings_country ON Locations.`country` = Findings_country.`country`
    LEFT JOIN Findings Findings_area ON Locations.`area` = Findings_area.`area`
    GROUP BY Locations.`id`
```

Here is [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2417c8/4)
Hope this helps..

Comment: Also works very nicely, and while I'm going to use @wchiquito's method (slightly better performance), you answered first so the accepted answer is yours. Thank you very much for your help! :)

Comment: yup instead of `case when` use `COALESCE`

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```sql
INSERT INTO `Summed`
SELECT
  `l`.`id`,
  COALESCE(
    `fcity`.`resultVM`,
    `fcountry`.`resultVM`,
    `farea`.`resultVM`,
    `fempty`.`resultVM`)
FROM
  `Locations` `l`
    LEFT JOIN `Findings` `fcity` ON `l`.`city` = `fcity`.`city`
    LEFT JOIN `Findings` `fcountry` ON `l`.`country` = `fcountry`.`country`
    LEFT JOIN `Findings` `farea` ON `l`.`area` = `farea`.`area`
    LEFT JOIN `Findings` `fempty` ON `fempty`.`city` = '' AND
                         `fempty`.`country` = '' AND
                         `fempty`.`area` = '';
```

<kbd>[SQL Fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c9b6d/2)</kbd>

Comment: Wow, I didn't even think about left joining the table multiple times... Works nicely and the performance is also much better than that of my previous method. Thank you very much! :)

Comment: @empir07: You may be able to improve (a litte bit) performance, see [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/90966/1).